# Trello API get attachment content with CURL?

Tags: guzzle, php-curl, trello

I found in [atlassian documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/rest-api/authorization/#passing-token-and-key-in-api-requests) this way to get [card attachment](https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/update-authenticated-access-to-s3/43681), but it doesn't work, I get here `unauthorized permission requested`.

`curl -H "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="MY_API_KEY", oauth_token="MY_USER_TOKEN"" https://trello.com/1/cards/e7c74l8c5ce3tf6424f95e76/attachments/71cdef9e0734215e3ccbfa82/download/cv.pdf`

I tried same with *guzzlehttp* but same result:

```
$params_arr = [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="' . $api_key . '", oauth_token="' . $token_key . '"'
            ]
        ];
        $request = $this->request($attachment_url, 'GET', $params_arr);
```

Does somebody have idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: so in both cases if you are getting unauthorized permission then I would suggest to check your auth key maybe copy paste error?

Comment: checked it already multiple times and all credentials are 100% correct

Comment: are you able to access any other apis eg `curl -H "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{{apiKey}}\", oauth_token=\"{{apiToken}}\"" https://api.trello.com/1/members/me`

Comment: I can call any other endpoint but attachment content reading doesn't work.

Comment: contact their help support if curl command line is also not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URL, replace `trello.com` with `api.trello.com`

The result will see something like this: `https://api.trello.com/1/cards/e7c74l8c5ce3tf6424f95e76/attachments/71cdef9e0734215e3ccbfa82/download/cv.pdf`